# Website not listed under Sites (in a Network environment)

Tags: multisite, network-admin

I have a Wordpress network installed, and the first website I created is not listed under the Sites entry in the top horizontal menu.

The second website I created is, along with the parent website.

If I go to Network > Sites, the first website is listed, and I can use the website fine, provided I type in the URL directly into the address bar.

Do you know the best method to add the site back into the Sites menu entry at top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the cause.

Under Network > Sites, there were no users listed next to the website in question.

My user account was listed next to the other two websites.

So, adding my user account as an administrator of the website added it back to the Sites menu.

I am not sure why my user account was not an administrator already.